# String or binary data would be truncated in asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm getting `String or binary data would be truncated` error when, I'm trying to execute

```
Insert into Student_info (StudentId,FirstName,LastName,DOB,StudentAddress,StudentEmail,StudentMobile) 
                         (Select StudentId,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Address,EmailId,Mobile from Student_temp where StudentId='" & studentid & "')
```

Table structure of `Student_Temp`

[image: here]

Table structure of `Student_Info`

[image: here]

Need Help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is reported by SQL Server when you try and insert string or binary data into a column which doesn't have enough width to hold it, e.g.

```
create table MyTable
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(10)
)

insert into MyTable (Column1) VALUES ('1234567890A')

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated
```

At a guess, it is because your `Student_info.StudentMobile` is `varchar(10)` whereas `Student_temp.Mobile is varchar(50)`

Comment: ok thanks, but, can you tell me in my scenario, where would be the error ? Since, the ddl statement of both tables are almost same, so i don't think so, the error, which you are talking about will be the main reason.

Comment: @coders - updated - I think it is the Mobile Number column widths. Out of interest, in this day and age it is worthwhile to model columns like Person's names as NVARCHAR in order to embrace the global community.

Comment: @StuartLC, I have the same problem, except I'm getting it, while inserting from vb.net and the field type of the field I'm inserting into is ntext. because usually in MySQL I use TEXT and their is no (or not such a small) size restriction.
the thing is; when inserting the data manually, it works...
any advice?

Comment: @pythonian29033 - I can't think of anything off-hand. Post a new question and I'm sure a guru will be able to solve this :)